# Adding custom metadata in PDFDocument

Tags: cocoa, pdf, metadata

I'm sending a document between the desktop and a handheld device, and I want to add a metadata header to a PDF like the following.

```
<CUSTOM_HEADER>\n
{"fileInfoEncodedInJson\":
   {"filename":"My Print Out",
   "filesize\":"630",
   "filedesc":"",}
   }\n
</CUSTOM_HEADER>\n
… file contents …
```

I've been using the PDFKit and PDFDocument which supplies the `documentAttributes` and `setDocumentAttributes` methods, but because it is a custom header, it doesn't seem to persist when I set the attributes and save the file:

```
NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/username/Desktop/file.pdf"];
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:path];

NSDictionary *docAttributes = [self.document documentAttributes];
NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:docAttributes];
[newAttributes setObject: @"Custom header contents" forKey:@"Custom header"];
docAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: newAttributes];

[document setDocumentAttributes: docAttributes];

//Here Custom Header is an entry in the dictionary

[self.document writeToFile:@"/Users/username/Desktop/UPDATEDfile.pdf"];

//Here the UPDATEDfile.pdf does not contain the custom header
```

I've been looking all over and I've found a couple of similar questions (like [here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/EditingPDFMetadata) on cocoadev for example) but no answers. Does anyone know of a way to store custom (i.e. not the 8 predefined constants provided under Document Attribute Keys) headers to PDF Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually edit the pre-existing headers, I simply created a NSMutableData object, added the text data first followed by the PDF data, then saved this data to the path I wanted.

```
 NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<CUSTOM_HEADER>\n {\"fileInfoEncodedInJson\":  {\"filename\":\"My Print Out\", \"filesize\":\"630\",\"filedesc\":\"\",}  }\n </CUSTOM_HEADER>\n"];

// Append header to PDF data
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[header dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:[doc dataRepresentation]];

[data writeToFile:@"/Users/username/Desktop/UPDATEDfile.pdf" atomically:NO];
```

This results in a PDF file that opens in Adobe for me, and the header is invisible when viewing.

Comment: In this situation the object offsets will be incorrect and the file is damaged. Adobe Reader can open the file (it repairs the cross references) but other PDF processors might complain about this. If your target is only Adobe Reader then you're fine.

Comment: You're correct.  In my specific case we are sending the file to a mobile app which requires this header and pushes the document to an Adobe Reader app, but thanks for the heads up.